# How to pass recordId to a variable in a lightning web component?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am attempting to print out the recordId of an account, using a variable inside a lightning web component. Here is my code so far:

javascript:

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';

export default class HelloWordAccount extends LightningElement {
@api recordId; //returns record id
message = this.recordId; //returns undefined?

}
```

html:

```
<template>
<ouput>{recordId}</ouput>
<br/> <br/>
<ouput>{message}</ouput>
</template>
```

The component is on the account page layout, and prints out the recordid inside of the output tags that reference "recordId". I want to pass the recordId to a variable ("message"), when I pass it to a variable, I get nothing. putting the value in an input tag prints out "undefined". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 things to be remembered here:

1. `recordId` will be loaded **after** the class has been initialised and the framework knows the record context and so when `message = this.recordId;` is executed, `recordId` will be undefined .
2. After setting the record context, `connectedCallback()` method is invoked and so you should use this method .
3. Properties should be declared [reactive (api, track & wire)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/js_props_reactive) when used in HTML so as to rerender when the value changes.

Below code will work:

```
@api recordId;
@track message;
connectedCallback() {
    this.message = this.recordId;
}
```